# Detecting cancel from android-oreo shortcut permission dialog & disallow duplicate shortcuts

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-shortcut

How to detect that user has denied permission to create pinned-shortcut?
There is no *cancel* callback in ShortcutManager class.

Since it is system dialog, is there a way to call permission as *startActivityForResult* and get result back? Like custom activity Gmail example: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html#pinned

and,

how to disallow *duplicate* shortcuts. Following code is creating same shortcut even if shortcut exists?

[image]

Code:

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    "com.abc.SplashActivity");
            ShortcutInfo pinShortcutInfo =
                    new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "unique-id").setShortLabel("UPI Shortcut").setIntent(getShortcutIntent()).setActivity(cn).build();

            Intent pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent =
                    mShortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent(pinShortcutInfo);

            pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

            PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                    pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent, 0);

            mShortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(pinShortcutInfo,
                    successCallback.getIntentSender());
```

Also, this code is working perfectly with Pixel emulator but drag-to-create-shortcut specifically is not working with *Essential* phone. After dragging icon, icon is dissapearing while you reach home.

Comment: found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

*How to disallow duplicate shortcuts?*

That's what you can do with this function. This function returns boolean whether that shortcut has been added before.

`shortcutManager.pinnedShortcuts` returns a list of currently available shortcuts.

```
 private fun checkShortcutIsAvailable(shortcutManager: ShortcutManager, app: App): Boolean {
    var exist = false
    for (shortcut in shortcutManager.pinnedShortcuts) {
        if (shortcut.id == app.id) {
            exist = true
            break
        }
    }
    return exist
}
```